Using if_else in a mutate command yields an error about false having the wrong size
Consider the following data:
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 x     = 1:9)

I now want to recode values by group based on a check if all values meet a certain threshold.
Using the code below leads to an error
df |> 
  mutate(test = if_else(all(x < 4), 0, x), .by = group)

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `test = if_else(all(x < 4), 0, x)`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = "a"`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must have size 1, not size 3.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

However, moving the criterion check out of the if_else command, works as expected.
df |> 
  mutate(helper = all(x < 4),
         test = if_else(helper == TRUE, 0, x), .by = group)

  group x helper test
1     a 1   TRUE    0
2     a 2   TRUE    0
3     a 3   TRUE    0
4     b 4  FALSE    4
5     b 5  FALSE    5
6     b 6  FALSE    6
7     c 7  FALSE    7
8     c 8  FALSE    8
9     c 9  FALSE    9

I have a vague idea why that is, i.e., the TRUE part is just a scalar (0) and the FALSE part in if_else represents all three rows in each group, but want to understand a bit more the issue here and why if_else doesn't recycle the shorter scalar to the length of the false statement.

if_else is a vectorized if...else.... This means that the first 3 arguments (condition, true, false) must all have the same length (in this case 3). And R won't recycle from 3 down to 1. If you don't want the helper column, use case_when instead.

Thanks. And good hint towards case_when, which is a bit confusing in itself that it does work here but not with if_else (I always thought about case_when as the generalization of if_else for more than one condition).

Since the result of all(x < 4) is either TRUE or FALSE once per group (the reason why dplyr::if_else/data.table::fifelse are not working) using if will recycle 0 or take the vector x (length 3).
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(test = if(all(x < 4)) 0 else x, .by = group)
  group x test
1     a 1    0
2     a 2    0
3     a 3    0
4     b 4    4
5     b 3    3
6     b 6    6
7     c 7    7
8     c 8    8
9     c 9    9

Note that ifelse works but might give the wrong results. It simply recycles the first value per group without complaining.
Data
(slightly modified)
df <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c",
"c"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")


This is also considerably faster then my initial solution or the case_when approach.
